# Filter Data in nested json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My angular controller is following -
    how to filter nested data like first row of json-

```
<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
  function VersionFilterCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.limit=6;
    $scope.orders = [
      { id:1, customer:[{ name: 'John1', id: 10 },{ name: 'John2', id: 100 }] },
      { id:2, customer: { name: 'William', id: 20 } },
      { id:3, customer: { name: 'John', id: 10 } },
      { id:4, customer: { name: 'William', id: 20 } },
      { id:5, customer: { name: 'Clive', id: 30 } }
    ];
  }
</script>
```

and my html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="VersionFilterCtrl">
    <input type='text' name='name' ng-model='search.customer.name'>
    <input type='text' name='name' ng-model='search.customer.id'>
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders| filterBy: ['customer.name']: search.customer.name| filterBy: ['customer.id']: search.customer.id">
      {{order.id}}{{order.customer.name}}
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9376x133/5/)

Comment: Please can you explain it more what do you want to search specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You approached this correctly in how you set up your search models to match the structure of the data you are filtering, i.e. `search.customer.name` and `search.customer.id`.

All you need to do is to apply the `search` object as the filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="order in orders | filter: search">
   {{order.id}} | id: {{order.customer.id}}  name: {{order.customer.name}}
</li>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WosMmUBrEQxwl8q2vnzU?p=preview)

A few other issues:

- There is no `filterBy` (unless you create your own)
- Your first order record has an array of customers - was this intentional? This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nqlsSxpK8U5BrMTNhhJ3?p=preview) handles that case